# how to start developing more cleaner editor's gui interface?

Tags: application-development, gui, text-editor

I'm using Ubuntu since one year and it got everything I need daily. I've written couple of applications like gps tracking and live video streaming in C++ with netbeans on Ubuntu.

The only drawback with Linux distributions so far I encountered is untidy gui interface for editors like gedit, netbeans, etc. These type of Applications have bigger buttons, bigger boundaries, untidy scroll bars, etc. I think all these applications share common API to generate graphical objects like buttons, scroll bars, etc.

I love coding in netbeans on Windows rather than on Ubuntu because of look and feel. I feel I have more screen estate in Windows applications than in Ubuntu.

- I want to try developing or redesigning these GUI objects like buttons, scroll bars etc.
- Where to start? At least through me some light on this..

Thank you.

Comment: Many editors have cleaner interfaces than the two you have mentioned.  QtCreator and SublimeText come to mind.  If you're talking about reskinning apps, Netbeans(Java) and Gedit or Geany(Gtk) are two completely different procedures.

Comment: Thank U hbdgaf. Can I ask you why Netbeans GUI on windows is cleaner than in linux? Yes I'm talking about reskinning. I will give a look at QtCreator and sublimetext.

Comment: Almost everything Java is universally ugly to me, so I can't say I find it any better on Windows.

Comment: yeah hbdgaf, I shouldn't've asked U!

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming you want to create your own GUI 
I recommend to use opengl if you want to have portable code between platforms.
you need to write draw functions that will draw the GUI element(such as text input fields/buttons...) and write event function that goes with them(on mouse click,on focus..).

Here is a [Tutorial](http://openglgui.sourceforge.net/tutorials.html) to get you started

Comment: Thank U! I will give a try. I read somewhere that opengl is not a good choice for developing simple gui interfaces rather I should go for GTK. What is your comment?

Comment: it's up to you really.
coding your own GUI is like re-inventing the wheel.
I didn't mention GTK and QT because they are frameworks and from your question i assumed you wanted full control over the GUI objects.

Comment: If we consider rhythm box and movieplayer they both got similar ugly GUIs. I think they are using GTK. If so then I want to contribute to GTK if it is opensource.

Comment: so can I use openGL to develop GTK?